# Help me find the number of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint sets such that

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
n(U)=60, & n(A\setminus B)=13, & n(B\setminus C)=16,\\
n(C\cap B)=4, & n(C\setminus A)=22, & n(A\cap C) = 5
\end{array}
$$

Find the following.

$a)$ $n(A\setminus(B\cup C))$

$b)$ $n((A\cup B\cup C)')$

$c)$ $n(C\setminus(A\cup B)')$

$d)$ $n(A\cap B)$

Thanks.

Comment: Is $U=A\cup B\cup C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be best to make a type of Venn Diagram.

$\hskip{.75in}$[image: venn1]

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint, so I'm not letting the blue and red circles touch. Let's start filling in parts. We know directly that:

$n(B\setminus C)=16$,

$n(C\cap B)=4$,

$n(A\cap C) = 5.$

$\hskip{.75in}$[image: venn2]

We can fill in the rest of the green $C$ circle knowing that $n(C\setminus A)=22$. This means there must be a total of $22$ in the green circle that isn't touching the blue $A$ circle. Since we already have $4$ in the green/red part, that leaves us with $18$ in the rest of the green $C$ circle.

We can fill in the rest of the blue $A$ circle from either $n(A\setminus B)=13$ or $n(U)=60$. In the latter case, we know $A + B + C = 60$, and since $B= 20$ and $C = 27$, that leaves us with $A = 13$, so the remaining blue should be $8$.

$\hskip{.75in}$[image: venn3]

This should help with parts $a$, $b$, and $c$. For part $d$, notice that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.